# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized with paypal

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

**Scenario**

Here I am doing direct payment with Credit Card with `paypal`, I am storing CC details in paypal account and `paypal` return Credit Card Token, And I am saving this Token number in my Database to do direct payment, And by the use of this token I am able to do direct payment with Sandbox account But when I am doing the same for live account than getting error as follow.

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

This is getting in my error response :

> {"name":"UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT","message":"Unauthorized
>   payment.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT","debug_id":"be6ad614a3843"}

This is code

```
try
{
    Dictionary<string, string> sdkConfig = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    sdkConfig.Add("mode", "live");
    string accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(PayPalConfig.PaypalClientId, PayPalConfig.PaypalClientSecret, sdkConfig).GetAccessToken();
    APIContext apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken);
    apiContext.Config = sdkConfig;

    // Items within a transaction.
    var item = new Item()
    {
        name = "Item Name",
        currency = "USD",
        price = "1",
        quantity = "8",
        sku = "sku"
    };

    // A resource representing a credit card that can be used to fund a payment.
    var credCardToken = new CreditCardToken()
    {
        credit_card_id = "Here CC Token Number"
    };

    var amnt = new Amount()
    {
       currency = "USD",
       total = "10",
       details = new Details()
       {
           shipping = "1",
           subtotal = "8",
           tax = "1"
       }
   };

   // A transaction defines the contract of a
   // payment - what is the payment for and who
   // is fulfilling it. 
   var tran = new Transaction()
   {
      amount = amnt,
      description = "This is the payment transaction description.",
      item_list = new ItemList() { items = new List<Item>() { item } }
   };

   // A resource representing a Payer's funding instrument. For stored credit card payments, set the CreditCardToken field on this object.
   var fundInstrument = new FundingInstrument()
   {
       credit_card_token = credCardToken
   };

   // A Payment Resource; create one using the above types and intent as 'sale'
   var pymnt = new Payment()
   {
       intent = "sale",
       payer = new Payer()
       {
           funding_instruments = new List<FundingInstrument>() { fundInstrument },
           payment_method = "credit_card"
       },
       transactions = new List<Transaction>() { tran }
    };

    // Create a payment using a valid APIContext
    var createdPayment = pymnt.Create(apiContext);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

If some one have any idea about this issue than please let me know. Or suggest me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: When you login to developer.paypal.com and click the Applications tab what does the account eligibility link on the left say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Happy to resolve this issue after a month,

**Reason :** There was no issue from My code side, Everything was correct but there was issue from `Paypal` side. In My Account I was unable to change **Direct credit cards** Permission option 'enable to green tick'. But now it is solve after the long discussion with `Paypal` team.You can see in below image. Hope this answer will helps others also.
[image]